# Is it safe to drink tap water in Darwin (Australia)?

Tags: australia, tap-water

Is tap water (from the kitchen sink of a holiday apartment) in Darwin, NT safe for human consumption ? 
I see algae (and fungus ?) on water fountains in public places so I am guessing those weren't meant to help thirsty travelers get a gulp. Is there a way to find safe public water drinking taps/fountains in Darwin ?

Comment: Algae in the 'sink' bit of a public fountain doesn't mean there's any problem with the water coming out the tap.

Comment: @jpatokal I wouldn't care about the algae in the sink. I am talking about the algae and moss and the disgust at the mouth of the tap - seeping within. Lemme see if I can get a pic for you

Answer (score 8):

An [informal survey](http://www.lifehacker.com.au/2011/08/australias-best-drinking-water-is-in-tasmania-and-the-nt/) showed a lot of claims that not only is it safe, but the *most* drinkable in Australia :)

However, all tap water in Darwin and the NT is monitored by [NT Department of Heath](http://www.health.nt.gov.au/environmental_health/water_quality/index.aspx).

> The Department's Environmental Health Branch has a key role in setting
>   goals for drinking water quality and monitoring compliance with those
>   objectives in the interest of public health.

This covers all tap water, making sure it is in line with the national guidelines.

In addition, they have rules for private supplies (eg groundwater):

> Operators of businesses or facilities that provide drinking water have
>   a responsibility to ensure that the water is safe to use. If the
>   safety of the water cannot be guaranteed then consumers should be
>   alerted.

*Note*: The [ADWG](http://www.health.nt.gov.au/environmental_health/water_quality/index.aspx#AustralianDrinkingWaterGuidelines2011ADWG) apply to any water intended for drinking, irrespective of the source or where it is consumed, with the exception of bottled and packaged water as it is covered under the national Food Standards Code.  Thus it should apply to your drinking fountains as well.

Comment: Any idea on who actually maintains the hygiene of the fountains? The operators of businesses are strange up here. Not a single pissable restroom, anywhere !

Comment: @happybuddha I'd assume some sort of council if they're in the parks/streets, but those on private property would be the responsibility of the private owners.